# tpm2.LoadExternal() throws error code 0x16 : unsupported symmetric algorithm or key size, or not appropriate for instance Error

Tags: c, go, cryptography, tpm

I have a DPE application and I am doing client.Sign of a message. This function returns a signature, a certificate from which we can get public key and other few things.

I have extracted the public key from this certificate and I found that that is of type ECDSA.

then I tried loading this public key into the TPM by using tpm2.loadexternal by forming tpm2.Public{} struct.

```
pubKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(publicKeyDer)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to parse DER-encoded public key:", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

// Create a tpm2.Public structure from the parsed ECDSA public key
switch pubKey := pubKey.(type) {
case *ecdsa.PublicKey:
    tpmPublic = tpm2.Public{
        Type:    tpm2.AlgECDSA, // ECDSA key type
        NameAlg: tpm2.AlgSHA256,
        //Attributes: tpm2.FlagSign | tpm2.FlagRestricted | tpm2.FlagDecrypt,
        Attributes: tpm2.FlagSign | tpm2.FlagSensitiveDataOrigin | tpm2.FlagUserWithAuth,
        ECCParameters: &tpm2.ECCParams{
            Symmetric: &tpm2.SymScheme{
                Alg:     tpm2.AlgECDSA,
                KeyBits: 2048,
                Mode:    tpm2.AlgSHA256,
            },
            Sign: &tpm2.SigScheme{
                Alg:  tpm2.AlgECDSA,
                Hash: tpm2.AlgSHA256,
                //Count: 0,
            },
            //CurveID: tpm2.EllipticCurve(0x0003), // You should adjust this based on your ECDSA curve
            CurveID: tpm2.CurveNISTP256,
            Point: tpm2.ECPoint{
                XRaw: new(big.Int).SetBytes(pubKey.X.Bytes()).Bytes(),
                YRaw: new(big.Int).SetBytes(pubKey.Y.Bytes()).Bytes(),
            },
        },
    }
default:
    fmt.Println("Unsupported public key type")
    os.Exit(1)
}

fmt.Printf("TPM2 Public Key:\n%v\n", tpmPublic)

// private := tpm2.Private{
//  Type: tpm2.AlgECC,
//  //Sensitive: pk.D.Bytes(),
// }

_, _, err = tpm2.LoadExternal(rwc, tpmPublic, tpm2.Private{}, tpm2.HandleNull)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Err : %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

for this loadExternal operation, I am getting below error,

```
Err : encoding RSAParameters, ECCParameters, SymCipherParameters or KeyedHash: unsupported type in TPMT_PUBLIC: 0x4543445341
exit status 1
```

if I change the type and Alg from ECDSA to ECC in all the places of the structure like,

```
Type:    tpm2.AlgECC
Alg:     tpm2.AlgECC
```

it throws,

```
Err : parameter 2, error code 0x16 : unsupported symmetric algorithm or key size, or not appropriate for instance
exit status 1
```

What am doing wrong here? first of all, Is the way I try to load a public key alone into the TPM correct? help me on this.

**Note :** I am not using real TPM instead I am using a TPM simulator by following (https://github.com/stefanberger/swtpm/wiki) and TPM related packages from (https://francislampayan.medium.com/how-to-setup-tpm-simulator-in-ubuntu-20-04-25ec673b88dc) this link.

Thanks..!

Comment: Why don't you study the source code of LoadExternal to see which checks fail and lead to returning of this error? For some reason you did not tell what is that `tpm2` package, but googling for the error message makes me confident it's [`github.com/google/go-tpm`](https://github.com/google/go-tpm/), and it's free software, meaning its sources are (freely) available.

Comment: I can see where it fails in the source. It is from,
(https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/blob/master/src/tss2-rc/tss2_rc.c#L252) 
 and tpm2 is (https://github.com/google/go-tpm). I am also debugging it. Meanwhile I posted here as well if someone knows about this already.

Comment: @kostix that looks like a TPM error code. In that case, looking into the source code will not help much.

Comment: @MemAllox, I mildly disagree: if it's a TPM error code, that is just fine: we ostensibly did some setup, which ostensibly included _setting up some crypto stuff,_ and then asked TPM to carry out some operation for us, which failed, but TPM said that it did not like something about our setup. So we can now correlate these two facts and try to tweak the setup. Basically, that's why I suggested looking at the source code, that wasn't a glib response ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by your error (`unsupported symmetric algorithm`): your symmetric crypto scheme is faulty.

```c
Symmetric: &tpm2.SymScheme{
    Alg:     tpm2.AlgECDSA,     <-- not a symmetric crypto scheme
    KeyBits: 2048,
    Mode:    tpm2.AlgSHA256,
},
```

You might want to try to leave that empty (`tpm2.AlgNull`):

https://github.com/folbricht/tpmk/blob/87ef9183fb67bc1cd4da7269f2b332c8d0991084/key.go#L24-L27

Or use AES:

https://github.com/google/go-tpm-tools/blob/44e8925789363b77e38c23bb5cf00eeae94be296/client/template.go#L35-L39

### Example of a working TPM2_LoadExternal call

```bash
Command                                   .
TPMI_ST_COMMAND_TAG                       |   .tag                                       8001                 TPMI_ST_COMMAND_TAG.NO_SESSIONS
UINT32                                    |   .commandSize                               00000068             104
TPM_CC                                    |   .commandCode                               00000167             TPM_CC.LoadExternal
TPMS_COMMAND_HANDLES_LOAD_EXTERNAL        |   .handles
TPMS_COMMAND_PARAMS_LOAD_EXTERNAL         |   .parameters
TPM2B_SENSITIVE                           |   |   .inPrivate
UINT16                                    |   |   |   .size                              0000                 0
TPMT_SENSITIVE                            |   |   |   .sensitiveArea
TPM2B_PUBLIC                              |   |   .inPublic
UINT16                                    |   |   |   .size                              0056                 86
TPMT_PUBLIC                               |   |   |   .publicArea
TPMI_ALG_PUBLIC                           |   |   |   |   .type                          0023                 TPMI_ALG_PUBLIC.ECC
TPMI_ALG_HASH                             |   |   |   |   .nameAlg                       000b                 TPMI_ALG_HASH.SHA256
TPMA_OBJECT                               |   |   |   |   .objectAttributes              00060040             393280
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .reserved                                       ...............................0
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .fixedTPM                                       ..............................0.
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .stClear                                        .............................0..
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .reserved0                                      ............................0...
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .fixedParent                                    ...........................0....
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .sensitiveDataOrigin                            ..........................0.....
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .userWithAuth                                   .........................1......
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .adminWithPolicy                                ........................0.......
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .reserved1                                      ......................00........
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .noDA                                           .....................0..........
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .encryptedDuplication                           ....................0...........
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .reserved2                                      ................0000............
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .restricted                                     ...............0................
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .decrypt                                        ..............1.................
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .sign_decrypt                                   .............1..................
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .sign                                           ............0...................
                                          |   |   |   |   |   .reserved3                                      000000000000....................
TPM2B_DIGEST                              |   |   |   |   .authPolicy
UINT16                                    |   |   |   |   |   .size                      0000                 0
list[BYTE]                                |   |   |   |   |   .buffer
TPMU_PUBLIC_PARMS                         |   |   |   |   .parameters
TPMS_ECC_PARMS                            |   |   |   |   |   .eccDetail
TPMT_SYM_DEF_OBJECT                       |   |   |   |   |   |   .symmetric
TPMI_ALG_SYM_OBJECT                       |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .algorithm         0010                 TPMI_ALG_SYM_OBJECT.NULL
TPMU_SYM_KEY_BITS                         |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .keyBits
TPMU_SYM_MODE                             |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .mode
TPMU_SYM_DETAILS                          |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .details
TPMT_ECC_SCHEME                           |   |   |   |   |   |   .scheme
TPMI_ALG_ECC_SCHEME                       |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .scheme            0010                 TPMI_ALG_ECC_SCHEME.NULL
TPMU_ASYM_SCHEME                          |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .details
TPMI_ECC_CURVE                            |   |   |   |   |   |   .curveID               0003                 TPMI_ECC_CURVE.NIST_P256
TPMT_KDF_SCHEME                           |   |   |   |   |   |   .kdf
TPMI_ALG_KDF                              |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .scheme            0010                 TPMI_ALG_KDF.NULL
TPMU_KDF_SCHEME                           |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .details
TPMU_PUBLIC_ID                            |   |   |   |   .unique
TPMS_ECC_POINT                            |   |   |   |   |   .ecc
TPM2B_ECC_PARAMETER                       |   |   |   |   |   |   .x
UINT16                                    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .size              0020                 32
list[BYTE]                                |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .buffer            f1ef85f33015e46293608004c167d9cfef3b4d37e01a19b6697930823da93d77 ....0..b.`...g...;M7....iy0.=.=w
TPM2B_ECC_PARAMETER                       |   |   |   |   |   |   .y
UINT16                                    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .size              0020                 32
list[BYTE]                                |   |   |   |   |   |   |   .buffer            9d845395e9720dcaf765255ce321c7f588e0b5c29f6355caf99953b741f47aed ..S..r...e%\.!.......cU...S.A.z.
TPMI_RH_HIERARCHY                         |   |   .hierarchy                             40000001             TPM_RH.OWNER

Response                                  .
TPM_ST                                    |   .tag                                       8001                 TPM_ST.NO_SESSIONS
UINT32                                    |   .responseSize                              00000032             50
TPM_RC                                    |   .responseCode                              00000000             TPM_RC.SUCCESS
TPMS_RESPONSE_HANDLES_LOAD_EXTERNAL       |   .handles
TPM_HANDLE                                |   |   .objectHandle                          80000002             TPM_HR.TRANSIENT.000002
TPMS_RESPONSE_PARAMS_LOAD_EXTERNAL        |   .parameters
TPM2B_NAME                                |   |   .name
UINT16                                    |   |   |   .size                              0022                 34
list[BYTE]                                |   |   |   .name                              000b81cda27e7bb1a82b4e8b04994a856cb838329451d4f834ec74a003c2c4a0c8a6 .....~{..+N...J.l.82.Q..4.t.......
```

### How I got it:

Start TPM simulator in its own terminal:

```bash
swtpm socket --tpm2 -p 2321 --ctrl type=tcp,port=2322 --log fd=1,level=5 --flags not-need-init --tpmstate dir=. --locality allow-set-locality
```

Generate key:

```bash
❯ openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
❯ openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout > key_public.pem
read EC key
writing EC key
```

Load key into TPM simulator and dump the traffic into `tpm2_log.pcap` (requires tpm2-tss >= v3.1.0):

```bash
❯ tpm2_startup -c -T swtpm
❯ tpm2_loadexternal -C o -Gecc -u key_public.pem -c key.ctx --tcti=swtpm
name: 000b81cda27e7bb1a82b4e8b04994a856cb838329451d4f834ec74a003c2c4a0c8a6
```

Decode the TPM traffic:

```bash
❯ tpmstream convert tpm2_log.pcap
# for output see above
```